# How do I create a type for two different object types that will satisfy same function parameter type

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have two types of object that is passing into a utility function which type A and B. How do I create a type that will satisfy both type A and B when passing into the utility function?

Type A

```
type A = { 
 num1: number,
 num2: number
}

const object: A = { 
 "num1": 1,
 "num2": 2
}
```

Type B

```
type B = {
  num1: number,
  isTrue: boolean,
  name: string
}
const object: B = { 
  "num1": 1,
  "isTrue": true,
  "name": "foobar"
}
```

Currently my utility function is to round up object key that is typeof `number`, I would like to not use any as its parameter type.

```
function(keys: any): any { 
  for (const key in keys) {
    if (typeof keys[key] === 'number') {
      keys[key] = Math.ceil(keys[key]);
    }
    return keys;
  }
}
function(object);
```

Comment: It would help if you would promote `A` and `B` to _named `type`_ statements instead of being anonymous.

Comment: I'm unsure how to make `keys[key] = Math.ceil(keys[key]);` work, I'll admit. So far I have this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAFWjAgnAvHA3nAdgVwFsBGALjyICMYAnAGgsICZyDDqa4BfAblEliJkAIQzZGZRhwYBLAM4Ia+GOUoB7NQBsYAQ1wNcOwirhywNGbgDm3PuGRDYAYTFJYaAGSOYwu-wduME4A0jAQcmIA1mFqAGbeTn4gsfi4AMZgMmq4cPiZmjKQAGKpGVm4ABTR4eSBIWFyANoAugCU5HoQ4qBwcLFqnBVp2WZw1XCWYw2t2D29E-EVAjBxU+GN1c0Y6JgA5GwcuzNYc-NrTZtiALI6YAAWAHRpMDKaVQ0bYW12Z1yncDQYGB8DQctU5D9uKAuEA

Comment: @Dai Thanks for ur suggestion, I just remember that my utility function would need to be more generic for others to use. I guess this defeat my question. I can just do `roundUpKeys<T>(keys: T): T ` instead 

Answer (score 0):

My utility function supposed to be generic in this case, I opt to make the function to accept generic type as below.

```
roundUpKeys<T>(keys: T): T {
        for (const key in keys) {
            if (typeof keys[key] === 'number') {
                keys[key] = Math.ceil(keys[key] as number) as T[typeof key];
            }
        }
        return keys;
    }
```

Comment: You can avoid `as number` but you can't avoid `as T[typeof key]`, because the compiler is rightly worried that maybe `T[typeof key]` might be *narrower* than number.  Imagine that `type C = { oneHalf: 0.5 }` and you pass a value of type `C` to your function; then the implementation will return a value of type `{ oneHalf: 1}` which doesn't conform.  You can try to prevent such things but the compiler can't follow the logic.  So [this](https://tsplay.dev/WvGKkw) is the closest I can imagine getting.  ...

Comment: ... Well, maybe instead of mutating the object you could make a copy, and abstract the unsafe stuff to its own property mapping function.  Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wy6exw).  If you want to see any of this as a separate answer, let me know.

Comment: @jcalz thank you for your explanation, learn something new about this